# ¿Se puede importar los datos de un "Excel" a multiples tablas? (Tablas relacionadas)

Tags: laravel-5, base-de-datos, excel, importación

Tengo una duda, quiero subir un archivo excel y que este importe la informacion obtenida. Se subirlo, pero no conozco la forma o el metodo (Si existe) para subir el archivo en varias tablas (Es un formato gigante, pero esta normalizado en la base de datos). Sus campos estan en varias tablas. ¿Hay alguna manera para poder importar los datos a todas las tablas existentes?

Answer (score 0):

Podria utilizar una librería para capturar toda la informacion del archivo excel, y guardarla en una base de datos, le recomiendo: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

Answer (score 0):

No se en que ámbito estas trabajando, pero hay varias opciones para importar desde un file a una base de datos de partida desde un editor sql, generalmente admiten la importación directa, ahora si hay que importar a una tabla especifica sería solo seleccionar la columna requerida, ahora si quieres algo más producido y suponiendo que estas trabajando en ambiente windows, hace años hice un montón de Macros para trabajar con excel y mandar a ejecutar directo en la base de datos a través de una conexión.

saludos.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow! Me temo que poner enlaces a sitios externos no ayuda ya que estos puede quedar obsoletos o ser inaccesibles. Por favor cualquier material que tengas compártelo en formato **texto** ya que las imágenes tampoco sirven... Un saludo :)

Comment: Ok, pero el texto es muy largo como para ponerlo en una respuesta.

Comment: Entiendo que pueda ser mucha información, intenta poner lo mas importante piensa que tampoco hace falta darle todo el trabajo hecho al usuario que pregunta , solo en lo que pida ayuda. Un saludo!

Comment: ok, eliminaré los enlaces